# How to parse the AndroidManifest.xml file inside an .apk package

Tags: android, android-manifest

This file appears to be in a binary XML format.  What is this format and how can it be parsed programmatically (as opposed to using the aapt dump tool in the SDK)?

This binary format is not discussed in the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

**Note**: I want to access this information from outside the Android environment, preferably from Java.

Comment: What is the specific use case you are after? A lot of the manifest information in your own app can be queried using `android.content.pm.PackageManager.queryXX` methods (docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).

Comment: I am not in an Android environment.  I want to read an .apk file, extract the AndroidManifest.xml and parse it as XML.

Comment: I have developed an APK extractor which is not dependent on AAPT. It includes parser which can parse any Android Binary XML content-
http://code.google.com/p/apk-extractor/

Answer (score 193, accepted):

## Use android-apktool

There is an application that reads apk files and decodes XMLs to nearly original form.

Usage:

```
apktool d Gmail.apk && cat Gmail/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Check [android-apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) for more information

Comment: A snippet to show its prowess may be nice: `apktool d Gmail.apk && cat Gmail/AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: `minSdkVersion` and other version parameters can also be found in `Gmail/apktool.yml`

Comment: How can this be used inside Android app exactly? And can it be used to get manifest data from InputStream (example: APK file exists inside zip file) ?

Comment: `apktool` does decode `AndroidManifest.xml`, but it doesn't decode every XML file that may be in the APK.

Answer (score 75):

This Java method, that runs on an Android, documents (what I've been able to interpret about) the binary format of the  AndroidManifest.xml file in the .apk package.  The second code box shows how to call decompressXML and how to load the byte[] from the app package file on the device.  (There are fields whose purpose I don't understand, if you know what they mean, tell me, I'll update the info.)

```
// decompressXML -- Parse the 'compressed' binary form of Android XML docs 
// such as for AndroidManifest.xml in .apk files
public static int endDocTag = 0x00100101;
public static int startTag =  0x00100102;
public static int endTag =    0x00100103;
public void decompressXML(byte[] xml) {
// Compressed XML file/bytes starts with 24x bytes of data,
// 9 32 bit words in little endian order (LSB first):
//   0th word is 03 00 08 00
//   3rd word SEEMS TO BE:  Offset at then of StringTable
//   4th word is: Number of strings in string table
// WARNING: Sometime I indiscriminently display or refer to word in 
//   little endian storage format, or in integer format (ie MSB first).
int numbStrings = LEW(xml, 4*4);

// StringIndexTable starts at offset 24x, an array of 32 bit LE offsets
// of the length/string data in the StringTable.
int sitOff = 0x24;  // Offset of start of StringIndexTable

// StringTable, each string is represented with a 16 bit little endian 
// character count, followed by that number of 16 bit (LE) (Unicode) chars.
int stOff = sitOff + numbStrings*4;  // StringTable follows StrIndexTable

// XMLTags, The XML tag tree starts after some unknown content after the
// StringTable.  There is some unknown data after the StringTable, scan
// forward from this point to the flag for the start of an XML start tag.
int xmlTagOff = LEW(xml, 3*4);  // Start from the offset in the 3rd word.
// Scan forward until we find the bytes: 0x02011000(x00100102 in normal int)
for (int ii=xmlTagOff; ii<xml.length-4; ii+=4) {
  if (LEW(xml, ii) == startTag) { 
    xmlTagOff = ii;  break;
  }
} // end of hack, scanning for start of first start tag

// XML tags and attributes:
// Every XML start and end tag consists of 6 32 bit words:
//   0th word: 02011000 for startTag and 03011000 for endTag 
//   1st word: a flag?, like 38000000
//   2nd word: Line of where this tag appeared in the original source file
//   3rd word: FFFFFFFF ??
//   4th word: StringIndex of NameSpace name, or FFFFFFFF for default NS
//   5th word: StringIndex of Element Name
//   (Note: 01011000 in 0th word means end of XML document, endDocTag)

// Start tags (not end tags) contain 3 more words:
//   6th word: 14001400 meaning?? 
//   7th word: Number of Attributes that follow this tag(follow word 8th)
//   8th word: 00000000 meaning??

// Attributes consist of 5 words: 
//   0th word: StringIndex of Attribute Name's Namespace, or FFFFFFFF
//   1st word: StringIndex of Attribute Name
//   2nd word: StringIndex of Attribute Value, or FFFFFFF if ResourceId used
//   3rd word: Flags?
//   4th word: str ind of attr value again, or ResourceId of value

// TMP, dump string table to tr for debugging
//tr.addSelect("strings", null);
//for (int ii=0; ii<numbStrings; ii++) {
//  // Length of string starts at StringTable plus offset in StrIndTable
//  String str = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, ii);
//  tr.add(String.valueOf(ii), str);
//}
//tr.parent();

// Step through the XML tree element tags and attributes
int off = xmlTagOff;
int indent = 0;
int startTagLineNo = -2;
while (off < xml.length) {
  int tag0 = LEW(xml, off);
  //int tag1 = LEW(xml, off+1*4);
  int lineNo = LEW(xml, off+2*4);
  //int tag3 = LEW(xml, off+3*4);
  int nameNsSi = LEW(xml, off+4*4);
  int nameSi = LEW(xml, off+5*4);

  if (tag0 == startTag) { // XML START TAG
    int tag6 = LEW(xml, off+6*4);  // Expected to be 14001400
    int numbAttrs = LEW(xml, off+7*4);  // Number of Attributes to follow
    //int tag8 = LEW(xml, off+8*4);  // Expected to be 00000000
    off += 9*4;  // Skip over 6+3 words of startTag data
    String name = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, nameSi);
    //tr.addSelect(name, null);
    startTagLineNo = lineNo;

    // Look for the Attributes
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int ii=0; ii<numbAttrs; ii++) {
      int attrNameNsSi = LEW(xml, off);  // AttrName Namespace Str Ind, or FFFFFFFF
      int attrNameSi = LEW(xml, off+1*4);  // AttrName String Index
      int attrValueSi = LEW(xml, off+2*4); // AttrValue Str Ind, or FFFFFFFF
      int attrFlags = LEW(xml, off+3*4);  
      int attrResId = LEW(xml, off+4*4);  // AttrValue ResourceId or dup AttrValue StrInd
      off += 5*4;  // Skip over the 5 words of an attribute

      String attrName = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, attrNameSi);
      String attrValue = attrValueSi!=-1
        ? compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, attrValueSi)
        : "resourceID 0x"+Integer.toHexString(attrResId);
      sb.append(" "+attrName+"=\""+attrValue+"\"");
      //tr.add(attrName, attrValue);
    }
    prtIndent(indent, "<"+name+sb+">");
    indent++;

  } else if (tag0 == endTag) { // XML END TAG
    indent--;
    off += 6*4;  // Skip over 6 words of endTag data
    String name = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, nameSi);
    prtIndent(indent, "</"+name+">  (line "+startTagLineNo+"-"+lineNo+")");
    //tr.parent();  // Step back up the NobTree

  } else if (tag0 == endDocTag) {  // END OF XML DOC TAG
    break;

  } else {
    prt("  Unrecognized tag code '"+Integer.toHexString(tag0)
      +"' at offset "+off);
    break;
  }
} // end of while loop scanning tags and attributes of XML tree
prt("    end at offset "+off);
} // end of decompressXML


public String compXmlString(byte[] xml, int sitOff, int stOff, int strInd) {
  if (strInd < 0) return null;
  int strOff = stOff + LEW(xml, sitOff+strInd*4);
  return compXmlStringAt(xml, strOff);
}


public static String spaces = "                                             ";
public void prtIndent(int indent, String str) {
  prt(spaces.substring(0, Math.min(indent*2, spaces.length()))+str);
}


// compXmlStringAt -- Return the string stored in StringTable format at
// offset strOff.  This offset points to the 16 bit string length, which 
// is followed by that number of 16 bit (Unicode) chars.
public String compXmlStringAt(byte[] arr, int strOff) {
  int strLen = arr[strOff+1]<<8&0xff00 | arr[strOff]&0xff;
  byte[] chars = new byte[strLen];
  for (int ii=0; ii<strLen; ii++) {
    chars[ii] = arr[strOff+2+ii*2];
  }
  return new String(chars);  // Hack, just use 8 byte chars
} // end of compXmlStringAt


// LEW -- Return value of a Little Endian 32 bit word from the byte array
//   at offset off.
public int LEW(byte[] arr, int off) {
  return arr[off+3]<<24&0xff000000 | arr[off+2]<<16&0xff0000
    | arr[off+1]<<8&0xff00 | arr[off]&0xFF;
} // end of LEW
```

This method reads the AndroidManifest into a byte[] for processing:

```
public void getIntents(String path) {
  try {
    JarFile jf = new JarFile(path);
    InputStream is = jf.getInputStream(jf.getEntry("AndroidManifest.xml"));
    byte[] xml = new byte[is.available()];
    int br = is.read(xml);
    //Tree tr = TrunkFactory.newTree();
    decompressXML(xml);
    //prt("XML\n"+tr.list());
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    console.log("getIntents, ex: "+ex);  ex.printStackTrace();
  }
} // end of getIntents
```

Most apps are stored in /system/app  which is readable without root my Evo, other apps are in /data/app which I needed root to see.  The 'path' argument above would be something like: "/system/app/Weather.apk"

Comment: A few of the attribute resource constants are defined in an enum in frameworks/base/tools/aapt/Command.cpp of the android source. This enum seems to grow between versions so a newer version would contain more definitions.

Comment: +1 for a tool that can be used outside of Android. I wrapped it as a working command-line Java tool; see http://pastebin.com/c53DuqMt.

Comment: Hello Ribo, I am using the above code to read xml file. Now what i wish to do is in my xml file, I have an attribute name whose value is specified by "@string/abc" & I want to hard-code it to some string. ie; remove the string reference. but the problem is I get the value of attrValueSi as -1. I am adding the keys in a map & I have the key entry in the map, I want to put the value in attrValueSi. How do I proceed ? Plz help.

Comment: @Ribo, just curious, how the hell did you figured that out ? (and thanks, it works)

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov, That was years ago, I don't remember.  Either I found some documentation or looked at the ASCII strings in the binary file and saw how it was converted.  I did that as part of the PackageExplorer app -- which was the first app I wrote.

Comment: @AndroidGuy, (sorry didn't see that comment earlier).  I'm not sure what you are asking.  You aren't asking about converting the binary XML file, but after you have the normal XML file (with <...> tags) you want to know how to specify a explicit string value rather than a string reference?

Comment: I love this snippet and have been using it for awhile. I do have a question about reading unicode characters though. When I run this over an APK whose label (or other fields) contains Unicode characters, the value comes out screwed up. Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: There's a pretty detailed description of the format in this blog post: http://justanapplication.wordpress.com/category/android/android-binary-xml/. I found it by browsing the source code of https://github.com/xiaxiaocao/apk-parser.

Comment: @corey-ogburn, change implementation of compXmlStringAt:

`
char[] chars = new char[strLen];
for (int ii = 0; ii < strLen; ii++) {
    chars[ii] = (char) (((arr[strOff + 2 + ii * 2 + 1] & 0x00FF) << 8) + (arr[strOff + 2 + ii * 2] & 0x00FF));
}`

Comment: @Ribo, I found, that attrFlags == 50331656 for string values, e.g. "1.2.1" (in version name); attrFlags == 268435464 for numbers, e.g. "12" (in version code); attrFlags == 16777224 for resourceIds (styles, strings, drawables, etc). Without this impossible to get correct, for example, versionCode.

Comment: So, when attrValueSi == -1, this is either resourceID or just a number. Value for both cases contains in attrResId

Comment: Has anyone tried this recently?  We are using Android Studio 3.0.1 and recently switched to cmake, and this no longer works.  Need to find out if it was AS or our build process change.

Comment: @Ribo It appears that this no longer works for Android Studio 3 and the new Gradle.  I would be interested in understanding more about how this worked as we use this. Was there someplace you found that had the algorithm to decrypt the manifest?

Comment: @GREnvoy We are also facing an issue here. We are getting a 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' exception

Comment: @Mad - See my most recent answer. I posted how I was able to get it to work with anothe Open source library.  The code in it is very similar to what Ribo had done. I wonder if the code is one and the same.

Comment: I ended up using @Ribo's code snippet and ran in the issue that is reported in this thread. There was no output. It turned out that the buffer was too small for the input file. After changing the buffer size to a higher value (in the main method), the xml was decompiled correctly.

Comment: No work, apktool reverse fine the xml content but the java project show a empty content only.

Comment: Anyone got this working on all types of APK files, without issues?

Comment: @BrianS Where is your recent answer? I can't find it.

Comment: @Giorgi I use apk-parser.  

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.dongliu/apk-parser

Answer (score 33):

What about using the **Android Asset Packaging Tool** (aapt), from the Android SDK, into a Python (or whatever) script?

Through the aapt (http://elinux.org/Android_aapt), indeed, you can retrieve information about the *.apk* package and about its *AndroidManifest.xml* file. In particular, you can extract the values of individual elements of an *.apk* package through the *'dump'* sub-command. For example, you can extract the **user-permissions** in the *AndroidManifest.xml* file inside an *.apk* package in this way:

```bash
$ aapt dump permissions package.apk
```

Where *package.apk* is your *.apk* package.

Moreover, you can use the Unix pipe command to clear the output. For example:

```bash
$ aapt dump permissions package.apk | sed 1d | awk '{ print $NF }'
```

Here a Python script that to that programmatically:

```py
import os
import subprocess

#Current directory and file name:
curpath = os.path.dirname( os.path.realpath(__file__) )
filepath = os.path.join(curpath, "package.apk")

#Extract the AndroidManifest.xml permissions:
command = "aapt dump permissions " + filepath + " | sed 1d | awk '{ print $NF }'"
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
permissions = process.communicate()[0]

print permissions
```

In a similar fashion you can extract other information (e.g. **package**, **app name**, etc...) of the *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
#Extract the APK package info:
shellcommand = "aapt dump badging " + filepath
process = subprocess.Popen(shellcommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
apkInfo = process.communicate()[0].splitlines()

for info in apkInfo:
    #Package info:
    if string.find(info, "package:", 0) != -1:
        print "App Package: " + findBetween(info, "name='", "'")
        print "App Version: " + findBetween(info, "versionName='", "'")
        continue

    #App name:
    if string.find(info, "application:", 0) != -1:
        print "App Name: " + findBetween(info, "label='", "'")
        continue


def findBetween(s, prefix, suffix):
    try:
        start = s.index(prefix) + len(prefix)
        end = s.index(suffix, start)
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""
```

If instead you want to parse the entire AndroidManifest XML tree, you can do that in a similar way using the *xmltree* command:

```bash
aapt dump xmltree package.apk AndroidManifest.xml
```

Using Python as before:

```
#Extract the AndroidManifest XML tree:
shellcommand = "aapt dump xmltree " + filepath + " AndroidManifest.xml"
process = subprocess.Popen(shellcommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
xmlTree = process.communicate()[0]

print "Number of Activities: " + str(xmlTree.count("activity"))
print "Number of Services: " + str(xmlTree.count("service"))
print "Number of BroadcastReceivers: " + str(xmlTree.count("receiver"))
```

Comment: Does this tool always exist on Android Roms ? Is it something that's always built in?

Comment: Way better if you ask me. :) I've got problems with apktool and AXMLPrinter2: sometimes they throw exceptions, etc. aapt works every time and is more versatile. Not to mention that it's the *official* tool.

Answer (score 20):

With the latest SDK-Tools, you can now use a tool called the apkanalyzer to print out the AndroidManifest.xml of an APK (as well as other parts, such as resources).

`[android sdk]/tools/bin/apkanalyzer manifest print [app.apk]`

[apkanalyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apkanalyzer.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! I had been googling this for days, and didn't want some third party solution that relies on python or perl or Java JARs or what have you.

Comment: This is the best answer given the current tools landscape.

Answer (score 17):

You can use **[axml2xml.pl](http://code.google.com/p/android-random/source/browse/trunk/axml2xml/axml2xml.pl)** tool developed a while ago within **android-random** project. It will generate the textual manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) from the binary one.

I'm saying "*textual*" and not "*original*" because like many reverse-engineering tools this one isn't perfect and *the result **will not** be complete*. I presume either it was never feature complete or simply not forward-compatible (with newer binary encoding scheme). Whatever the reason, **axml2xml.pl** tool will not be able to extract all the attribute values correctly. Such attributes are minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion and basically all attributes that are referencing resources (like strings, icons, etc.), i.e. only class names (of activities, services, etc.) are extracted correctly.

However, you can still find these missing information by running **aapt** tool on the original Android app file (**.apk**):

> **aapt l -a *<someapp.apk>***

Comment: Thanks @Shonzilla. I need package name and version code information, the aapt does the job. As I am working with LAMP, I run aapt command in PHP and process the output with PHP.

Comment: Any Java/Kotlin solution that could work for Android?

Answer (score 13):

apk-parser, https://github.com/caoqianli/apk-parser, a lightweight impl for java, with no dependency for aapt or other binarys, is good for parse binary xml files, and other apk infos.

```
ApkParser apkParser = new ApkParser(new File(filePath));
// set a locale to translate resource tag into specific strings in language the locale specified, you set locale to Locale.ENGLISH then get apk title 'WeChat' instead of '@string/app_name' for example
apkParser.setPreferredLocale(locale);

String xml = apkParser.getManifestXml();
System.out.println(xml);

String xml2 = apkParser.transBinaryXml(xmlPathInApk);
System.out.println(xml2);

ApkMeta apkMeta = apkParser.getApkMeta();
System.out.println(apkMeta);

Set<Locale> locales = apkParser.getLocales();
for (Locale l : locales) {
    System.out.println(l);
}
apkParser.close();
```

Comment: Not tested. It should work, but someone do report issues with android L.

Comment: I see. Can you get the intent-filters this way?

Comment: Intent-filters can be obtained by parsing manifest xml file, no direct method now.

Comment: "pure java", a deeply unfortunate phrase

Answer (score 11):

Check this following [WPF Project](http://androidxmldotnet.codeplex.com) which decodes the properties correctly.

Comment: +1 for this, Thanks!!! For C# developers, I definitely recommend this. Saved me a lot of time =)
It held me back for a while because I had to run "aapt" to retrieve version number and package name (which is not possible given that my scenario is in web environment and user needs feedback after retrieving both package name and version number).

Comment: You can actually easily remove the PresentationCore dependency, it is only used for its Color class. You can either create your own one, or use System.Drawing.

Comment: Is there a solution like this, but one that works inside Android app?

Answer (score 8):

If your into Python or use [Androguard](https://code.google.com/p/androguard/), the Androguard Androaxml feature will do this conversion for you.  The feature is detailed in [this blog post](http://androguard.blogspot.com/2011/03/androids-binary-xml.html), with additional [documentation here](https://code.google.com/p/androguard/wiki/Usage#Androaxml) and [source here](https://code.google.com/p/androguard/source/browse/androaxml.py).

Usage:

```
$ ./androaxml.py -h
Usage: androaxml.py [options]

Options:
-h, --help            show this help message and exit
-i INPUT, --input=INPUT
                      filename input (APK or android's binary xml)
-o OUTPUT, --output=OUTPUT
                      filename output of the xml
-v, --version         version of the API

$ ./androaxml.py -i yourfile.apk -o output.xml
$ ./androaxml.py -i AndroidManifest.xml -o output.xml
```

Answer (score 8):

@Mathieu Kotlin version follows:

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val fileName = "app.apk"
    ZipFile(fileName).use { zip ->
        zip.entries().asSequence().forEach { entry ->
            if(entry.name == "AndroidManifest.xml") {
                zip.getInputStream(entry).use { input ->
                    val xml = decompressXML(input.readBytes())
                    //TODO: parse the XML
                    println(xml)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    /**
     * Binary XML doc ending Tag
     */
    var endDocTag = 0x00100101

    /**
     * Binary XML start Tag
     */
    var startTag = 0x00100102

    /**
     * Binary XML end Tag
     */
    var endTag = 0x00100103


    /**
     * Reference var for spacing
     * Used in prtIndent()
     */
    var spaces = "                                             "


    /**
     * Parse the 'compressed' binary form of Android XML docs
     * such as for AndroidManifest.xml in .apk files
     * Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package/4761689#4761689
     *
     * @param xml Encoded XML content to decompress
     */
    fun decompressXML(xml: ByteArray): String {

        val resultXml = StringBuilder()

        // Compressed XML file/bytes starts with 24x bytes of data,
        // 9 32 bit words in little endian order (LSB first):
        //   0th word is 03 00 08 00
        //   3rd word SEEMS TO BE:  Offset at then of StringTable
        //   4th word is: Number of strings in string table
        // WARNING: Sometime I indiscriminently display or refer to word in
        //   little endian storage format, or in integer format (ie MSB first).
        val numbStrings = LEW(xml, 4 * 4)

        // StringIndexTable starts at offset 24x, an array of 32 bit LE offsets
        // of the length/string data in the StringTable.
        val sitOff = 0x24  // Offset of start of StringIndexTable

        // StringTable, each string is represented with a 16 bit little endian
        // character count, followed by that number of 16 bit (LE) (Unicode) chars.
        val stOff = sitOff + numbStrings * 4  // StringTable follows StrIndexTable

        // XMLTags, The XML tag tree starts after some unknown content after the
        // StringTable.  There is some unknown data after the StringTable, scan
        // forward from this point to the flag for the start of an XML start tag.
        var xmlTagOff = LEW(xml, 3 * 4)  // Start from the offset in the 3rd word.
        // Scan forward until we find the bytes: 0x02011000(x00100102 in normal int)
        run {
            var ii = xmlTagOff
            while (ii < xml.size - 4) {
                if (LEW(xml, ii) == startTag) {
                    xmlTagOff = ii
                    break
                }
                ii += 4
            }
        } // end of hack, scanning for start of first start tag

        // XML tags and attributes:
        // Every XML start and end tag consists of 6 32 bit words:
        //   0th word: 02011000 for startTag and 03011000 for endTag
        //   1st word: a flag?, like 38000000
        //   2nd word: Line of where this tag appeared in the original source file
        //   3rd word: FFFFFFFF ??
        //   4th word: StringIndex of NameSpace name, or FFFFFFFF for default NS
        //   5th word: StringIndex of Element Name
        //   (Note: 01011000 in 0th word means end of XML document, endDocTag)

        // Start tags (not end tags) contain 3 more words:
        //   6th word: 14001400 meaning??
        //   7th word: Number of Attributes that follow this tag(follow word 8th)
        //   8th word: 00000000 meaning??

        // Attributes consist of 5 words:
        //   0th word: StringIndex of Attribute Name's Namespace, or FFFFFFFF
        //   1st word: StringIndex of Attribute Name
        //   2nd word: StringIndex of Attribute Value, or FFFFFFF if ResourceId used
        //   3rd word: Flags?
        //   4th word: str ind of attr value again, or ResourceId of value

        // TMP, dump string table to tr for debugging
        //tr.addSelect("strings", null);
        //for (int ii=0; ii<numbStrings; ii++) {
        //  // Length of string starts at StringTable plus offset in StrIndTable
        //  String str = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, ii);
        //  tr.add(String.valueOf(ii), str);
        //}
        //tr.parent();

        // Step through the XML tree element tags and attributes
        var off = xmlTagOff
        var indent = 0
        var startTagLineNo = -2
        while (off < xml.size) {
            val tag0 = LEW(xml, off)
            //int tag1 = LEW(xml, off+1*4);
            val lineNo = LEW(xml, off + 2 * 4)
            //int tag3 = LEW(xml, off+3*4);
            val nameNsSi = LEW(xml, off + 4 * 4)
            val nameSi = LEW(xml, off + 5 * 4)

            if (tag0 == startTag) { // XML START TAG
                val tag6 = LEW(xml, off + 6 * 4)  // Expected to be 14001400
                val numbAttrs = LEW(xml, off + 7 * 4)  // Number of Attributes to follow
                //int tag8 = LEW(xml, off+8*4);  // Expected to be 00000000
                off += 9 * 4  // Skip over 6+3 words of startTag data
                val name = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, nameSi)
                //tr.addSelect(name, null);
                startTagLineNo = lineNo

                // Look for the Attributes
                val sb = StringBuffer()
                for (ii in 0 until numbAttrs) {
                    val attrNameNsSi = LEW(xml, off)  // AttrName Namespace Str Ind, or FFFFFFFF
                    val attrNameSi = LEW(xml, off + 1 * 4)  // AttrName String Index
                    val attrValueSi = LEW(xml, off + 2 * 4) // AttrValue Str Ind, or FFFFFFFF
                    val attrFlags = LEW(xml, off + 3 * 4)
                    val attrResId = LEW(xml, off + 4 * 4)  // AttrValue ResourceId or dup AttrValue StrInd
                    off += 5 * 4  // Skip over the 5 words of an attribute

                    val attrName = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, attrNameSi)
                    val attrValue = if (attrValueSi != -1)
                        compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, attrValueSi)
                    else
                        "resourceID 0x" + Integer.toHexString(attrResId)
                    sb.append(" $attrName=\"$attrValue\"")
                    //tr.add(attrName, attrValue);
                }
                resultXml.append(prtIndent(indent, "<$name$sb>"))
                indent++

            } else if (tag0 == endTag) { // XML END TAG
                indent--
                off += 6 * 4  // Skip over 6 words of endTag data
                val name = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, nameSi)
                resultXml.append(prtIndent(indent, "</$name>  (line $startTagLineNo-$lineNo)"))
                //tr.parent();  // Step back up the NobTree

            } else if (tag0 == endDocTag) {  // END OF XML DOC TAG
                break

            } else {
                        println("  Unrecognized tag code '" + Integer.toHexString(tag0)
                            + "' at offset " + off
                )
                break
            }
        } // end of while loop scanning tags and attributes of XML tree
        println("    end at offset $off")

        return resultXml.toString()
    } // end of decompressXML


    /**
     * Tool Method for decompressXML();
     * Compute binary XML to its string format
     * Source: Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package/4761689#4761689
     *
     * @param xml Binary-formatted XML
     * @param sitOff
     * @param stOff
     * @param strInd
     * @return String-formatted XML
     */
    fun compXmlString(xml: ByteArray, sitOff: Int, stOff: Int, strInd: Int): String? {
        if (strInd < 0) return null
        val strOff = stOff + LEW(xml, sitOff + strInd * 4)
        return compXmlStringAt(xml, strOff)
    }


    /**
     * Tool Method for decompressXML();
     * Apply indentation
     *
     * @param indent Indentation level
     * @param str String to indent
     * @return Indented string
     */
    fun prtIndent(indent: Int, str: String): String {

        return spaces.substring(0, Math.min(indent * 2, spaces.length)) + str
    }


    /**
     * Tool method for decompressXML()
     * Return the string stored in StringTable format at
     * offset strOff.  This offset points to the 16 bit string length, which
     * is followed by that number of 16 bit (Unicode) chars.
     *
     * @param arr StringTable array
     * @param strOff Offset to get string from
     * @return String from StringTable at offset strOff
     */
    fun compXmlStringAt(arr: ByteArray, strOff: Int): String {
        val strLen = (arr[strOff + 1] shl (8 and 0xff00)) or (arr[strOff].toInt() and 0xff)
        val chars = ByteArray(strLen)
        for (ii in 0 until strLen) {
            chars[ii] = arr[strOff + 2 + ii * 2]
        }
        return String(chars)  // Hack, just use 8 byte chars
    } // end of compXmlStringAt


    /**
     * Return value of a Little Endian 32 bit word from the byte array
     * at offset off.
     *
     * @param arr Byte array with 32 bit word
     * @param off Offset to get word from
     * @return Value of Little Endian 32 bit word specified
     */
    fun LEW(arr: ByteArray, off: Int): Int {
        return (arr[off + 3] shl 24 and -0x1000000 or ((arr[off + 2] shl 16) and 0xff0000)
                or (arr[off + 1] shl 8 and 0xff00) or (arr[off].toInt() and 0xFF))
    } // end of LEW

    private infix fun Byte.shl(i: Int): Int = (this.toInt() shl i)
    private infix fun Int.shl(i: Int): Int = (this shl i)
```

This is a kotlin version of the answer above.

Comment: Sadly this seems to have issues on some rare cases. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60565299/878126

Answer (score 7):

In case it's useful, here's a C++ version of the Java snippet posted by Ribo:

```cpp
struct decompressXML
{
    // decompressXML -- Parse the 'compressed' binary form of Android XML docs 
    // such as for AndroidManifest.xml in .apk files
    enum
    {
        endDocTag = 0x00100101,
        startTag =  0x00100102,
        endTag =    0x00100103
    };

    decompressXML(const BYTE* xml, int cb) {
    // Compressed XML file/bytes starts with 24x bytes of data,
    // 9 32 bit words in little endian order (LSB first):
    //   0th word is 03 00 08 00
    //   3rd word SEEMS TO BE:  Offset at then of StringTable
    //   4th word is: Number of strings in string table
    // WARNING: Sometime I indiscriminently display or refer to word in 
    //   little endian storage format, or in integer format (ie MSB first).
    int numbStrings = LEW(xml, cb, 4*4);

    // StringIndexTable starts at offset 24x, an array of 32 bit LE offsets
    // of the length/string data in the StringTable.
    int sitOff = 0x24;  // Offset of start of StringIndexTable

    // StringTable, each string is represented with a 16 bit little endian 
    // character count, followed by that number of 16 bit (LE) (Unicode) chars.
    int stOff = sitOff + numbStrings*4;  // StringTable follows StrIndexTable

    // XMLTags, The XML tag tree starts after some unknown content after the
    // StringTable.  There is some unknown data after the StringTable, scan
    // forward from this point to the flag for the start of an XML start tag.
    int xmlTagOff = LEW(xml, cb, 3*4);  // Start from the offset in the 3rd word.
    // Scan forward until we find the bytes: 0x02011000(x00100102 in normal int)
    for (int ii=xmlTagOff; ii<cb-4; ii+=4) {
      if (LEW(xml, cb, ii) == startTag) { 
        xmlTagOff = ii;  break;
      }
    } // end of hack, scanning for start of first start tag

    // XML tags and attributes:
    // Every XML start and end tag consists of 6 32 bit words:
    //   0th word: 02011000 for startTag and 03011000 for endTag 
    //   1st word: a flag?, like 38000000
    //   2nd word: Line of where this tag appeared in the original source file
    //   3rd word: FFFFFFFF ??
    //   4th word: StringIndex of NameSpace name, or FFFFFFFF for default NS
    //   5th word: StringIndex of Element Name
    //   (Note: 01011000 in 0th word means end of XML document, endDocTag)

    // Start tags (not end tags) contain 3 more words:
    //   6th word: 14001400 meaning?? 
    //   7th word: Number of Attributes that follow this tag(follow word 8th)
    //   8th word: 00000000 meaning??

    // Attributes consist of 5 words: 
    //   0th word: StringIndex of Attribute Name's Namespace, or FFFFFFFF
    //   1st word: StringIndex of Attribute Name
    //   2nd word: StringIndex of Attribute Value, or FFFFFFF if ResourceId used
    //   3rd word: Flags?
    //   4th word: str ind of attr value again, or ResourceId of value

    // TMP, dump string table to tr for debugging
    //tr.addSelect("strings", null);
    //for (int ii=0; ii<numbStrings; ii++) {
    //  // Length of string starts at StringTable plus offset in StrIndTable
    //  String str = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, ii);
    //  tr.add(String.valueOf(ii), str);
    //}
    //tr.parent();

    // Step through the XML tree element tags and attributes
    int off = xmlTagOff;
    int indent = 0;
    int startTagLineNo = -2;
    while (off < cb) {
      int tag0 = LEW(xml, cb, off);
      //int tag1 = LEW(xml, off+1*4);
      int lineNo = LEW(xml, cb, off+2*4);
      //int tag3 = LEW(xml, off+3*4);
      int nameNsSi = LEW(xml, cb, off+4*4);
      int nameSi = LEW(xml, cb, off+5*4);

      if (tag0 == startTag) { // XML START TAG
        int tag6 = LEW(xml, cb, off+6*4);  // Expected to be 14001400
        int numbAttrs = LEW(xml, cb, off+7*4);  // Number of Attributes to follow
        //int tag8 = LEW(xml, off+8*4);  // Expected to be 00000000
        off += 9*4;  // Skip over 6+3 words of startTag data
        std::string name = compXmlString(xml, cb, sitOff, stOff, nameSi);
        //tr.addSelect(name, null);
        startTagLineNo = lineNo;

        // Look for the Attributes
        std::string sb;
        for (int ii=0; ii<numbAttrs; ii++) {
          int attrNameNsSi = LEW(xml, cb, off);  // AttrName Namespace Str Ind, or FFFFFFFF
          int attrNameSi = LEW(xml, cb, off+1*4);  // AttrName String Index
          int attrValueSi = LEW(xml, cb, off+2*4); // AttrValue Str Ind, or FFFFFFFF
          int attrFlags = LEW(xml, cb, off+3*4);  
          int attrResId = LEW(xml, cb, off+4*4);  // AttrValue ResourceId or dup AttrValue StrInd
          off += 5*4;  // Skip over the 5 words of an attribute

          std::string attrName = compXmlString(xml, cb, sitOff, stOff, attrNameSi);
          std::string attrValue = attrValueSi!=-1
            ? compXmlString(xml, cb, sitOff, stOff, attrValueSi)
            : "resourceID 0x"+toHexString(attrResId);
          sb.append(" "+attrName+"=\""+attrValue+"\"");
          //tr.add(attrName, attrValue);
        }
        prtIndent(indent, "<"+name+sb+">");
        indent++;

      } else if (tag0 == endTag) { // XML END TAG
        indent--;
        off += 6*4;  // Skip over 6 words of endTag data
        std::string name = compXmlString(xml, cb, sitOff, stOff, nameSi);
        prtIndent(indent, "</"+name+">  (line "+toIntString(startTagLineNo)+"-"+toIntString(lineNo)+")");
        //tr.parent();  // Step back up the NobTree

      } else if (tag0 == endDocTag) {  // END OF XML DOC TAG
        break;

      } else {
        prt("  Unrecognized tag code '"+toHexString(tag0)
          +"' at offset "+toIntString(off));
        break;
      }
    } // end of while loop scanning tags and attributes of XML tree
    prt("    end at offset "+off);
    } // end of decompressXML


    std::string compXmlString(const BYTE* xml, int cb, int sitOff, int stOff, int strInd) {
      if (strInd < 0) return std::string("");
      int strOff = stOff + LEW(xml, cb, sitOff+strInd*4);
      return compXmlStringAt(xml, cb, strOff);
    }

    void prt(std::string str)
    {
        printf("%s", str.c_str());
    }
    void prtIndent(int indent, std::string str) {
        char spaces[46];
        memset(spaces, ' ', sizeof(spaces));
        spaces[min(indent*2,  sizeof(spaces) - 1)] = 0;
        prt(spaces);
        prt(str);
        prt("\n");
    }


    // compXmlStringAt -- Return the string stored in StringTable format at
    // offset strOff.  This offset points to the 16 bit string length, which 
    // is followed by that number of 16 bit (Unicode) chars.
    std::string compXmlStringAt(const BYTE* arr, int cb, int strOff) {
        if (cb < strOff + 2) return std::string("");
      int strLen = arr[strOff+1]<<8&0xff00 | arr[strOff]&0xff;
      char* chars = new char[strLen + 1];
      chars[strLen] = 0;
      for (int ii=0; ii<strLen; ii++) {
          if (cb < strOff + 2 + ii * 2)
          {
              chars[ii] = 0;
              break;
          }
        chars[ii] = arr[strOff+2+ii*2];
      }
      std::string str(chars);
      free(chars);
      return str;
    } // end of compXmlStringAt


    // LEW -- Return value of a Little Endian 32 bit word from the byte array
    //   at offset off.
    int LEW(const BYTE* arr, int cb, int off) {
      return (cb > off + 3) ? ( arr[off+3]<<24&0xff000000 | arr[off+2]<<16&0xff0000
          | arr[off+1]<<8&0xff00 | arr[off]&0xFF ) : 0;
    } // end of LEW

    std::string toHexString(DWORD attrResId)
    {
        char ch[20];
        sprintf_s(ch, 20, "%lx", attrResId);
        return std::string(ch);
    }
    std::string toIntString(int i)
    {
        char ch[20];
        sprintf_s(ch, 20, "%ld", i);
        return std::string(ch);
    }
};
```

Comment: Two bugs: In compXMLStringAt: `chars` is allocated by new char[], but then free'd, instead of the correct `delete[] chars;`. At the end of the decompressXML ctor it must be `prt("    end at offset "+toIntString(off));`, otherwise pointer arithmetic is used...

Answer (score 5):

In Android studio 2.2 you can directly analyze the apk. Goto build- analyze apk. Select the apk, navigate to androidmanifest.xml. You can see the details of androidmanifest.

Comment: You can also simply just open the APK via File->Open...

Answer (score 3):

for reference here is my version of Ribo's code. The main difference is that decompressXML() directly returns a String, which for my purposes was a more appropriate usage.

NOTE: my sole purpose in using Ribo's solution was to fetch an .APK file's published version from the Manifest XML file, and I confirm that for this purpose it works beautifully.

EDIT [2013-03-16]: It works beautifully **IF** the version is set as plain text, but if it's set to refer to a Resource XML, it'll show up as 'Resource 0x1' for example. In this particular case, you'll probably have to couple this solution to another solution that will fetch the proper string resource reference.

```
/**
 * Binary XML doc ending Tag
 */
public static int endDocTag = 0x00100101;

/**
 * Binary XML start Tag
 */
public static int startTag =  0x00100102;

/**
 * Binary XML end Tag
 */
public static int endTag =    0x00100103;


/**
 * Reference var for spacing
 * Used in prtIndent()
 */
public static String spaces = "                                             ";


/**
 * Parse the 'compressed' binary form of Android XML docs 
 * such as for AndroidManifest.xml in .apk files
 * Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package/4761689#4761689
 * 
 * @param xml Encoded XML content to decompress
 */
public static String decompressXML(byte[] xml) {

    StringBuilder resultXml = new StringBuilder();

    // Compressed XML file/bytes starts with 24x bytes of data,
    // 9 32 bit words in little endian order (LSB first):
    //   0th word is 03 00 08 00
    //   3rd word SEEMS TO BE:  Offset at then of StringTable
    //   4th word is: Number of strings in string table
    // WARNING: Sometime I indiscriminently display or refer to word in 
    //   little endian storage format, or in integer format (ie MSB first).
    int numbStrings = LEW(xml, 4*4);

    // StringIndexTable starts at offset 24x, an array of 32 bit LE offsets
    // of the length/string data in the StringTable.
    int sitOff = 0x24;  // Offset of start of StringIndexTable

    // StringTable, each string is represented with a 16 bit little endian 
    // character count, followed by that number of 16 bit (LE) (Unicode) chars.
    int stOff = sitOff + numbStrings*4;  // StringTable follows StrIndexTable

    // XMLTags, The XML tag tree starts after some unknown content after the
    // StringTable.  There is some unknown data after the StringTable, scan
    // forward from this point to the flag for the start of an XML start tag.
    int xmlTagOff = LEW(xml, 3*4);  // Start from the offset in the 3rd word.
    // Scan forward until we find the bytes: 0x02011000(x00100102 in normal int)
    for (int ii=xmlTagOff; ii<xml.length-4; ii+=4) {
      if (LEW(xml, ii) == startTag) { 
        xmlTagOff = ii;  break;
      }
    } // end of hack, scanning for start of first start tag

    // XML tags and attributes:
    // Every XML start and end tag consists of 6 32 bit words:
    //   0th word: 02011000 for startTag and 03011000 for endTag 
    //   1st word: a flag?, like 38000000
    //   2nd word: Line of where this tag appeared in the original source file
    //   3rd word: FFFFFFFF ??
    //   4th word: StringIndex of NameSpace name, or FFFFFFFF for default NS
    //   5th word: StringIndex of Element Name
    //   (Note: 01011000 in 0th word means end of XML document, endDocTag)

    // Start tags (not end tags) contain 3 more words:
    //   6th word: 14001400 meaning?? 
    //   7th word: Number of Attributes that follow this tag(follow word 8th)
    //   8th word: 00000000 meaning??

    // Attributes consist of 5 words: 
    //   0th word: StringIndex of Attribute Name's Namespace, or FFFFFFFF
    //   1st word: StringIndex of Attribute Name
    //   2nd word: StringIndex of Attribute Value, or FFFFFFF if ResourceId used
    //   3rd word: Flags?
    //   4th word: str ind of attr value again, or ResourceId of value

    // TMP, dump string table to tr for debugging
    //tr.addSelect("strings", null);
    //for (int ii=0; ii<numbStrings; ii++) {
    //  // Length of string starts at StringTable plus offset in StrIndTable
    //  String str = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, ii);
    //  tr.add(String.valueOf(ii), str);
    //}
    //tr.parent();

    // Step through the XML tree element tags and attributes
    int off = xmlTagOff;
    int indent = 0;
    int startTagLineNo = -2;
    while (off < xml.length) {
      int tag0 = LEW(xml, off);
      //int tag1 = LEW(xml, off+1*4);
      int lineNo = LEW(xml, off+2*4);
      //int tag3 = LEW(xml, off+3*4);
      int nameNsSi = LEW(xml, off+4*4);
      int nameSi = LEW(xml, off+5*4);

      if (tag0 == startTag) { // XML START TAG
        int tag6 = LEW(xml, off+6*4);  // Expected to be 14001400
        int numbAttrs = LEW(xml, off+7*4);  // Number of Attributes to follow
        //int tag8 = LEW(xml, off+8*4);  // Expected to be 00000000
        off += 9*4;  // Skip over 6+3 words of startTag data
        String name = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, nameSi);
        //tr.addSelect(name, null);
        startTagLineNo = lineNo;

        // Look for the Attributes
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int ii=0; ii<numbAttrs; ii++) {
          int attrNameNsSi = LEW(xml, off);  // AttrName Namespace Str Ind, or FFFFFFFF
          int attrNameSi = LEW(xml, off+1*4);  // AttrName String Index
          int attrValueSi = LEW(xml, off+2*4); // AttrValue Str Ind, or FFFFFFFF
          int attrFlags = LEW(xml, off+3*4);  
          int attrResId = LEW(xml, off+4*4);  // AttrValue ResourceId or dup AttrValue StrInd
          off += 5*4;  // Skip over the 5 words of an attribute

          String attrName = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, attrNameSi);
          String attrValue = attrValueSi!=-1
            ? compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, attrValueSi)
            : "resourceID 0x"+Integer.toHexString(attrResId);
          sb.append(" "+attrName+"=\""+attrValue+"\"");
          //tr.add(attrName, attrValue);
        }
        resultXml.append(prtIndent(indent, "<"+name+sb+">"));
        indent++;

      } else if (tag0 == endTag) { // XML END TAG
        indent--;
        off += 6*4;  // Skip over 6 words of endTag data
        String name = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, nameSi);
        resultXml.append(prtIndent(indent, "</"+name+">  (line "+startTagLineNo+"-"+lineNo+")"));
        //tr.parent();  // Step back up the NobTree

      } else if (tag0 == endDocTag) {  // END OF XML DOC TAG
        break;

      } else {
          Log.e(TAG, "  Unrecognized tag code '"+Integer.toHexString(tag0)
          +"' at offset "+off);
        break;
      }
    } // end of while loop scanning tags and attributes of XML tree
    Log.i(TAG, "    end at offset "+off);

    return resultXml.toString();
} // end of decompressXML


/**
 * Tool Method for decompressXML();
 * Compute binary XML to its string format 
 * Source: Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package/4761689#4761689
 * 
 * @param xml Binary-formatted XML
 * @param sitOff
 * @param stOff
 * @param strInd
 * @return String-formatted XML
 */
public static String compXmlString(byte[] xml, int sitOff, int stOff, int strInd) {
  if (strInd < 0) return null;
  int strOff = stOff + LEW(xml, sitOff+strInd*4);
  return compXmlStringAt(xml, strOff);
}


/**
 * Tool Method for decompressXML(); 
 * Apply indentation
 * 
 * @param indent Indentation level
 * @param str String to indent
 * @return Indented string
 */
public static String prtIndent(int indent, String str) {

    return (spaces.substring(0, Math.min(indent*2, spaces.length()))+str);
}


/** 
 * Tool method for decompressXML()
 * Return the string stored in StringTable format at
 * offset strOff.  This offset points to the 16 bit string length, which 
 * is followed by that number of 16 bit (Unicode) chars.
 * 
 * @param arr StringTable array
 * @param strOff Offset to get string from
 * @return String from StringTable at offset strOff
 * 
 */
public static String compXmlStringAt(byte[] arr, int strOff) {
  int strLen = arr[strOff+1]<<8&0xff00 | arr[strOff]&0xff;
  byte[] chars = new byte[strLen];
  for (int ii=0; ii<strLen; ii++) {
    chars[ii] = arr[strOff+2+ii*2];
  }
  return new String(chars);  // Hack, just use 8 byte chars
} // end of compXmlStringAt


/** 
 * Return value of a Little Endian 32 bit word from the byte array
 *   at offset off.
 * 
 * @param arr Byte array with 32 bit word
 * @param off Offset to get word from
 * @return Value of Little Endian 32 bit word specified
 */
public static int LEW(byte[] arr, int off) {
  return arr[off+3]<<24&0xff000000 | arr[off+2]<<16&0xff0000
    | arr[off+1]<<8&0xff00 | arr[off]&0xFF;
} // end of LEW
```

Hope it can help other people too.

Comment: If an APK's manifest file refers to String resource xml for Version, Your this code fails. in my case i downloaded an APK from https://github.com/stephanenicolas/RoboDemo/robodemo-sample-1.0.1.apk/qr_code and ran your code on it. Instead of printing versions, it print Resource ID. i.e "resourceID 0x1" which is useless and to findout that resource id we need another program which can findout that resource file and decompile it.

Comment: This make total sense. To be honest, it did not occur to me that the version could have been referred to in a Resource XML instead of plain text.
I will edit my post to cover for that particularity.

Comment: can you please tell me how i can decode String.xml and findout that particular resource id. I want to use it this in my university project. to create Build Management System

Comment: @Cheeta to be honest I don't know any more than you do. I simply took Ribo's code and modified it for my specific needs, then shared it in case someone else can benefit. I suggest looking for a solution specific to retrieving String Resources from a .APK, and couple it with the one I published here. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found the AXMLPrinter2, a Java app over at the Android4Me project to work fine on the AndroidManifest.xml that I had (and prints the XML out in a nicely formatted way).
http://code.google.com/p/android4me/downloads/detail?name=AXMLPrinter2.jar

One note.. it (and the code on this answer from Ribo) doesn't appear to handle every compiled XML file that I've come across. I found one where the strings were stored with one byte per character, rather than the double byte format that it assumes.

Comment: I can't reach this link. Any alternative?

Comment: works fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

I have been running with the Ribo code posted above for over a year, and it has served us well. With recent updates (Gradle 3.x) though, I was no longer able to parse the AndroidManifest.xml, I was getting index out of bounds errors, and in general it was no longer able to parse the file.

**Update:** I now believe that our issues was with upgrading to Gradle 3.x. This article describes how AirWatch had issues and can be fixed by using a Gradle setting to use aapt instead of aapt2 [AirWatch seems to be incompatible with Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0-beta1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967668/airwatch-seems-to-be-incompatible-with-android-plugin-for-gradle-3-0-0-beta1)

In searching around I came across this open source project, and it's being maintained and I was able to get to the point and read both my old APKs that I could previously parse, and the new APKs that the logic from Ribo threw exceptions

https://github.com/xgouchet/AXML

From his example this is what I'm doing

```
  zf = new ZipFile(apkFile);

  //Getting the manifest
  ZipEntry entry = zf.getEntry("AndroidManifest.xml");
  InputStream is = zf.getInputStream(entry);

     // Read our manifest Document
     Document manifestDoc = new CompressedXmlParser().parseDOM(is);

     // Make sure we got a doc, and that it has children
     if (null != manifestDoc && manifestDoc.getChildNodes().getLength() > 0) {
        //
        Node firstNode = manifestDoc.getFirstChild();

        // Now get the attributes out of the node
        NamedNodeMap nodeMap = firstNode.getAttributes();

        // Finally to a point where we can read out our values
        versionName = nodeMap.getNamedItem("android:versionName").getNodeValue();
        versionCode = nodeMap.getNamedItem("android:versionCode").getNodeValue();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

apkanalyzer will be helpful

```
@echo off

::##############################################################################
::##
::##  apkanalyzer start up script for Windows
::##
::##  converted by ewwink
::##
::##############################################################################

::Attempt to set APP_HOME

SET SAVED=%cd%
SET APP_HOME=C:\android\sdk\tools
SET APP_NAME="apkanalyzer"

::Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and APKANALYZER_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
SET DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=%APP_HOME%

SET CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\dvlib-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\util-2.2.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\jimfs-1.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\annotations-13.0.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\ddmlib-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\repository-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\sdk-common-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\kotlin-stdlib-1.1.3-2.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\apkanalyzer-cli.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\gson-2.3.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\httpcore-4.2.5.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\dexlib2-2.2.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\commons-compress-1.12.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\generator.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\error_prone_annotations-2.0.18.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\commons-codec-1.6.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\kxml2-2.3.0.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\httpmime-4.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\annotations-12.0.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\jsr305-3.0.0.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\explainer.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\builder-model-3.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\baksmali-2.2.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\layoutlib-api-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\jcommander-1.64.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\annotations-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\builder-test-api-3.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\httpclient-4.2.6.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\common-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\jopt-simple-4.9.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\sdklib-26.0.0-dev.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\apkanalyzer.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\shared.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\binary-resources.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\guava-22.0.jar

SET APP_ARGS=%*
::Collect all arguments for the java command, following the shell quoting and substitution rules
SET APKANALYZER_OPTS=%DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% -classpath %CLASSPATH% com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli %APP_ARGS%

::Determine the Java command to use to start the JVM.
SET JAVACMD="java"
where %JAVACMD% >nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel%==1 (
  echo ERROR: 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
  echo Please set the 'java' variable in your environment to match the
  echo location of your Java installation.
  echo.
  exit /b 0
)

:: execute apkanalyzer

%JAVACMD% %APKANALYZER_OPTS%
```

original post https://stackoverflow.com/a/51905063/1383521

Comment: refer to @Alther answer

Answer (score -1):

it can be helpful

```
public static int vCodeApk(String path) {
    PackageManager pm = G.context.getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(path, 0);
    return info.versionCode;
    //        Toast.makeText(this, "VersionCode : " + info.versionCode + ", VersionName : " + info.versionName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

G is my Application class :

```
public class G extends Application {
```