# PHP: How to get version from android .apk file?

Tags: php, xml, android, version, apk

I am trying to create a PHP script to get the app version from Android APK file. 
Extracting XML file from the APK (zip) file and then parsing XML is one way, but I guess it should be simpler. Something like [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php), example #3.
Any ideas how to create the script?

Comment: Do you have the possibility to install the Android SDK on the server?

Comment: Where is the zip located you want to get the informatin about?

Comment: @Francesco: Without Android SDK
@Kau-Boy: zip (apk) file is located on server with php scripts
Is it possible to do something like in link I posted (example #3)?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you have the Android SDK installed on the server, you can use PHP's exec (or similar) to execute the `aapt` tool (in `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-X/tools`).

```
$ aapt dump badging myapp.apk
```

And the output should include:

```
package: name='com.example.myapp' versionCode='1530' versionName='1.5.3'
```

If you *can't* install the Android SDK, for whatever reason, then you will need to parse Android's binary XML format.  The `AndroidManifest.xml` file inside the APK zip structure is **not** plain text.

You would need to port a [utility like AXMLParser](http://code.google.com/p/android4me/source/browse/src/android4me/res/AXMLParser.java) from Java to PHP.

Comment: Without Android SDK on server, with PHP script. I am looking in for solution like in link I posted (example #3)

Comment: @ChristopherOrr Can you provide an example about the first way, I can't run it through my Windows Server!

Comment: @ChristopherOrr My Code `exec("e:\\Develop files\\androidsdk\\platform-tools\\aapt.exe \\aapt dump badging bz.apk",$resultSet); print_r($resultSet);`

Answer (score 10):

I've created a set of PHP functions that will find just the Version Code of an APK. This is based on the fact that the AndroidMainfest.xml file contains the version code as the first tag, and based on the axml (binary Android XML format) as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package/14814245#14814245)

```
    <?php
$APKLocation = "PATH TO APK GOES HERE";

$versionCode = getVersionCodeFromAPK($APKLocation);
echo $versionCode;

//Based on the fact that the Version Code is the first tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file, this will return its value
//PHP implementation based on the AXML format described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package/14814245#14814245
function getVersionCodeFromAPK($APKLocation) {

    $versionCode = "N/A";

    //AXML LEW 32-bit word (hex) for a start tag
    $XMLStartTag = "00100102";

    //APK is esentially a zip file, so open it
    $zip = zip_open($APKLocation);
    if ($zip) {
        while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
            //Look for the AndroidManifest.xml file in the APK root directory
            if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) == "AndroidManifest.xml") {
                //Get the contents of the file in hex format
                $axml = getHex($zip, $zip_entry);
                //Convert AXML hex file into an array of 32-bit words
                $axmlArr = convert2wordArray($axml);
                //Convert AXML 32-bit word array into Little Endian format 32-bit word array
                $axmlArr = convert2LEWwordArray($axmlArr);
                //Get first AXML open tag word index
                $firstStartTagword = findWord($axmlArr, $XMLStartTag);
                //The version code is 13 words after the first open tag word
                $versionCode = intval($axmlArr[$firstStartTagword + 13], 16);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    zip_close($zip);

    return $versionCode;
}

//Get the contents of the file in hex format
function getHex($zip, $zip_entry) {
    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, 'r')) {
        $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
        $hex = unpack("H*", $buf);
        return current($hex);
    }
}

    //Given a hex byte stream, return an array of words
function convert2wordArray($hex) {
    $wordArr = array();
    $numwords = strlen($hex)/8;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numwords; $i++)
        $wordArr[] = substr($hex, $i * 8, 8);

    return $wordArr;
}

//Given an array of words, convert them to Little Endian format (LSB first)
function convert2LEWwordArray($wordArr) {
    $LEWArr = array();

    foreach($wordArr as $word) {
        $LEWword = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word)/2; $i++)
            $LEWword .= substr($word, (strlen($word) - ($i*2) - 2), 2);
        $LEWArr[] = $LEWword;
    }

    return $LEWArr;
}

//Find a word in the word array and return its index value
function findWord($wordArr, $wordToFind) {
    $currentword = 0;
    foreach ($wordArr as $word) {
        if ($word == $wordToFind)
            return $currentword;
        else
            $currentword++;
    }
}
    ?>
```

Comment: hi @CHeil402 how to get versionname

Answer (score 1):

Use this in the CLI:

```
apktool if 1.apk
aapt dump badging 1.apk
```

You can use these commands in PHP using `exec` or `shell_exec`.

Answer (score 1):

```
aapt dump badging ./apkfile.apk | grep sdkVersion -i
```

You will get a human readable form.

```
sdkVersion:'14'
targetSdkVersion:'14'
```

Just look for aapt in your system if you have Android SDK installed.
Mine is in:

```
<SDKPATH>/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt
```

Answer (score 1):

The dump format is a little odd and not the easiest to work with. Just to expand on some of the other answers, this is a shell script that I am using to parse out name and version from APK files.

```
aapt d badging PACKAGE | gawk $'match($0, /^application-label:\'([^\']*)\'/, a) { n = a[1] }
                               match($0, /versionName=\'([^\']*)\'/, b) { v=b[1] }
                               END { if ( length(n)>0 && length(v)>0 ) { print n, v } }'
```

If you just want the version then obviously it can be much simpler.

```
aapt d badging PACKAGE | gawk $'match($0, /versionName=\'([^\']*)\'/, v) { print v[1] }'
```

Here are variations suitable for both gawk and mawk (a little less durable in case the dump format changes but should be fine):

```
aapt d badging PACKAGE | mawk -F\' '$1 ~ /^application-label:$/ { n=$2 }
                                    $5 ~ /^ versionName=$/ { v=$6 }
                                    END{ if ( length(n)>0 && length(v)>0 ) { print n, v } }'

aapt d badging PACKAGE | mawk -F\' '$5 ~ /^ versionName=$/ { print $6 }'
```