# PHP - get apk package name when upload to server

Tags: php, android

Is it possible to get the package name of an apk when the apk file is being uploaded to the server in php.

Comment: probably same question as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014369/php-how-to-get-version-from-android-apk-file

Answer (score 3):

Look at this package. it does what you need.

[php Apk Parser](https://github.com/tufanbarisyildirim/php-apk-parser)