# Reading Activity names from apk file in Android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, apk

I want to extract all the `activities` names from an android apk file.
Any idea how possibly it can be done?

Comment: this should work for manifest too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868768/extracting-android-apk-and-reading-contents-of-xml-file-in-res-layout

Comment: I want to do this programatically, will this be still useful?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the PackageManager method [getPackageArchiveInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageArchiveInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to retrieve the information from an APK file. Assuming your APK lives in the root of your SD card, you can use this code:

```
    String apkPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
                   + "/MyApp.apk";
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkPath, 
                           PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    //Log.i("ActivityInfo", "Package name is " + info.packageName);

    for (android.content.pm.ActivityInfo a : info.activities) {
        Log.i("ActivityInfo", a.name);
    }
```

There is plenty of additional information you can find in the ActivityInfo and PackageInfo objects.

Answer (score 20):

If you just want to list them from the command line you can use

```
aapt dump xmltree <apk-file> AndroidManifest.xml
```

The format is a bit perplexing at first, but all the info is there.

You need the Android SDK installed to do this, of course.

Comment: Great tip. Please make this an answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547703/list-all-activities-within-an-apk-from-the-shell

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the full path to the APK, just call the following directly from inside an Activity.

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
PackageInfo packageInfo = manager.getPackageInfo("your package name", PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
```