# List all activities within an APK from the shell

Tags: android

Is there a way to list all the activities of a particular .apk file from the shell?  I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084716/list-of-all-activities-in-app) which describes how to list all the activities in an apk but it is not for the shell.

Comment: Are you doing this on the device or on the computer?

Comment: I'm using adb shell to connect to an emulator (though being able to adb shell on a device would be nice)

Comment: The aapt command can do that. See my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728903/reading-activity-names-from-apk-file-in-android

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you can pull out the apk file to your own machine, you can use the aapt command in the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

```
aapt dump xmltree <apk-file> AndroidManifest.xml
```

The format is a bit perplexing at first, but all the info is there.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that the ``aapt`` binary can be found under the ``<sdk_dir>/build-tools/<version>/`` directory

Comment: Seems to have moved to build-tools\<version>\

Answer (score 5):

The solution from @Albin will print all the elements in `AndroidManifest.xml`, we need to filter the output. Here is another solution only print activities as the question ask.

```
aapt list -a /path/to/the/apk | sed -n '/ activity /{:loop n;s/^.*android:name.*="\([^"]\{1,\}\)".*/\1/;T loop;p;t}'
```