# Get All Activities by using package Name

Tags: android, package-managers, android-package-managers

I want to get all activities present in Application as a list by using PackageInfo. Please tell me is there any way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok try this it ll help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669277/how-to-get-all-homescreens-in-android/23670155#23670155

Comment: This is i know, it is used to get all applications list. But i want to get all activities names in application

Comment: @Leena you mean, you want to get all activities name from one application or from all installed applications?

Comment: @Leena see my answer, if it should be workful to you

Comment: ok i got it, please check this method of package manager getPackageArchiveInfo(archiveFilePath, flags); ,here you can Retrieve overall information about an application package defined in a package archive file. and set flag GET_ACTIVITIES.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got answer to my question as follows.

```
public static ArrayList<ActivityInfo> getAllRunningActivities(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageInfo pi = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(pi.activities));

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of hardcoding the package name like "com.mobeta.android.demodslv" I would use `Context.getPackageName()` to make the code re-usable from project to project

Comment: One should note that this method only returns the enabled/exported activities, not necessarily all listed in the AndroidManifest.xml file. To retrieve all activities, one has to parse the manifest or use aapt, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547703/list-all-activities-within-an-apk-from-the-shell.