# I need to open my .doc file in quickoffice in my app without looking for suitable apps (options)

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to open my .doc file in quickoffice in my app without looking for suitable apps (options).

Here I have used this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    //String type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
    //      MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString()));
    //intent.setDataAndType(uri, type == null ? "*/*" : type);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");

    startActivity((Intent.createChooser(intent,
            getString(R.string.open_using))));
```

This Code shows suitable target apps which i dont need actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me.

```
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        Intent quickOffice = packageManager
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.quickoffice.android");

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //your file location
        File file = new File(sdcard, "Meta Data.doc");
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);

        quickOffice.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        quickOffice.setDataAndType(path, "application/msword");// ---->application/msword

        startActivity(quickOffice);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the createChooser call, and just pass the intent to startActivity.  Then it will open the default app for the mime type, assuming one is set.  If none is set, it may still pop up a chooser among those apps which claim they can open it.  If you want to only open quick office you can do so by activity name, but then it will fail (and possibly throw an exception) if quick office is not installed.

Comment: Thanks@ Gabe But i dont konw how to get the activity name of quickoffice. How can I know that?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728903/reading-activity-names-from-apk-file-in-android, which has info on how to read apk files manually and programatically.