# Retrieve manifest data from our market website

Tags: android, package, manifest, vps

We are creating a market to selling android apps on it. But we have a problem here.
Our site is asp.net based & we have a VPS. now, my question is how can we get the manifest information like package name, package number, permissions etc when a user uploads its apk file to store them in DB?
I want the system to automatically do this for me to do packagename comparisons and etc

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question, but as a first step you should know that an apk is [simply a zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470139/how-to-get-application-or-package-info-from-the-apk-file-in-the-android-applicat). Therefore, by expanding, you can access the manifest xml, and read the values you need. How you do this, depends on your dev team (this is an asp.net question now!).

In order to decompile the XML you can use this parser for dot net: http://androidxmldotnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: the problem is manifest.xml file is compiled and need a decompiler

Comment: I think i must use it in the eclise project?