# Use antivirus in the application to scan files

Tags: android, antivirus, interfacing

I was trying to develop an application in android which should use some antivirus engine (preferably opensource) to scan the files on the device. Have searched a lot on internet but couldn't found any. Anybody please suggest me some antivirus engines that I can bundle with my app and also an example how I can integrate it in my app.
Thank you.

edit: Need open source anti-virus libraries which provides APIs so that the third party applications can use the libraries & APIs in the code and scan the files, generate reports etc.,

Comment: "use some antivirus to scan" <== Did you mean 'call' another antivirus app to scan files?

Comment: yes exactly..want to use SDK of antivirus.

Comment: search for anti virus in google play (AVG, Zoner, Lookout, etc.) and then go to their site and see if they offer an API to scan files.

Comment: There were no such free AV engine 4 years back but now I can see few public APIs. My current app needs it and this is what I have found [OpenAV] (https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/openav-developing-open-source-antivirus-engines) [VirusTotal] (https://www.virustotal.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this, but you can do something like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.example.package", "com.example.package.ActivityToStart");
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.package");
startActivity(intent);
```

See: [Calling an app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674391/calling-an-app-from-another-app)
This require you must know application package name of another app that installed in phone. (Go to phone setting -> manage application).

Comment: I want the SDK of antivirus. I heard that some antivirus organizations provides some SDK(or some interface) to be used in third party applications to scan the malicious files.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help, I have never heard about AV SDK or open source.

Comment: @Kishore - when you ask for something as indistinct as "the SDK of antivirus" there is no justification for downvoting responses that interpret that to mean something different than what you wanted.  That's especially true since this answer was posted **after** you confirmed in comments that you wanted a way to "call" another anti-virus app, which is precisely what this answer provides.
"

Comment: @Chris Stratton: Let me first clarify that the down-vote is not by me. Second thing is i have up voted for the answer that is why it is 0 now. One more point is that just now i have found some thing which proves the question is not indistinct. 
http://www.opswat.com/products/oesis-framework   | 
http://www.opswat.com/products/metascan          |
http://www.opswat.com/products/appremover

Comment: That you can find something matching your impression of the term does not mean that it has a distinct enough meaning to result in the answers you expect here.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: Sorry if i have hurt you. I thought the question is very helpful for business/security applications.

Comment: The problem isn't with your goal, it's with not being clear about what sort of solution you want.  Do you want an antivirus engine which you can bundle with your app, a source of definitions for that, or do you want a recommendation of a separate app (or even, though of limited practicality, a web service) which you can pass requests or files to and have it scan them and give you the result.

Comment: @Kishore any updates on this? Did you finally find the SDK?

Comment: @PabloMartinez Sorry for getting back late. I didn't find such SDK, So we have developed our own propitiatory framework.

Comment: @PabloMartinez please refer sziraqui's comment on the question. It looks similar. Might be helpful.