# iOS launch application from another

Tags: android, iphone, ios

Is it possible to have an application on an Iphone (or android) that can pull in the phones native apps and launch them from within that app? If it is possible, do you think it would be within Apple's standards to get on their app store?

Comment: give an brief example of what you want

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible you can use like this...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"appURL"]];
```

Comment: do you think it would be within Apple's standards to get on their app store?

Comment: I think u got your answer by @simpleBob.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would first have to create a scheme for the app you want to launch. For example something like `myapp://`, this way, when a URL starts with your scheme it will be opened (or may be chosen to open if there are more apps with the same scheme).

You set the scheme at your XXX-Info.plist, here is an example:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.mycompany.myapp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myapp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

After the scheme is set, you can open it with safari or another app by calling

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myapp://myparameters"]];
```

[Click here for more info](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

**UPDATE**

For Android see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674391/calling-an-app-from-another-app)

Comment: do you think it would be within Apple's standards to get on their app store?

Comment: @Eric YES! you will have no problems with Apple because of implementing a scheme. After all, it is the OS which decides to call your app. There are no private or 3rd party libraries involved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in iPhone using `openURL`.

Register the Custom URL Scheme

[image]

then

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"rajneesh071://"]];`

Just follow this link for detail information [Link](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2013/03/ios-sdk-open-other-app-from-our-app.html)

Comment: do you think it would be within Apple's standards to get on their app store?

Comment: YES! you will have no problems with Apple

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html