# How to read a AndroidManifest.xml (in binary) file?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read the content of the AndroiadManifest.xml file which seems to be in  "DBase 3 data file" binary format.

Is there any code example in Java on how to read this binary file? I don't need write, just read the text content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse the AndroidManifest.xml file inside an .apk package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package)

Answer (score -2):

Step 1: First you need to extract .apk file using apktool

Step 2: Now we want to read the androidmanifest.xml file using Java DOM XML parser
ex. want to read "uses-permission" tag form a androidmanifest.xml

```
public class parse_xml 
  {
    public static void main(String argv[]) 
    {
    try {
    File fXmlFile= new File("C:\\apkfolder\\AndroidManifest.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root element :"+ doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    NodeList nList= doc.getElementsByTagName("uses-permission");
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        //System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;


            System.out.println(eElement.getAttribute("android:name"));

               }

    }
       System.out.println("total no. of permissions"+ nList.getLength());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
}
```