# How to use from axml in java (read and write AndroidManifest.xml file in java)

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

(This question isn't duplicate !) I want to read the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in **java** and, as needed, edit and save it. How can I do this with [**`Axml`**](https://github.com/Sable/axml) ?

There was no guidance on [this](https://github.com/Sable/axml) page to use it and after a day I could not learn how to use it. Please tell me how to use ***`Axml`*** (please give code example) .

Comment: What is the exact situation do you have?? Can you explain the scenario why do you need to do so ??

Comment: I have a "AndroidManifest.xml" file on my memory card that I want to change and need to delete or add permission to it.

Comment: How did you get that file?? strange is it your own application file?? first of all, you can never change others build apk file or this will not perform for you.

Comment: I've extracted this file from another program and, for some reason, I want to edit this file. I do not want to use this file in my current program just want to edit it.

Comment: for sure you can edit this file by opening the whole project in android studio. But you can never make any build using that packagename, because you will never get the XML (Layout Files) for that project. And editing someone else code will not make any sense. 
Try to make some original (your own)

Comment: Your talk about what you say can not be edited by another program file is incorrect.
Examples of this file to be read:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105818/how-to-read-a-androidmanifest-xml-in-binary-file

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package

But I want to read this file with the "Axml" library.

Comment: I am saying you that you can not make any built using your edited file. read comment carefully.

Comment: Please go to [this page](https://github.com/Sable/axml) to find out what I mean.
Please tell me how to use this library.