# Get apk file icon, version, name in delphi

Tags: delphi, icons, apk

Is there a way I can get application name, application version and application icon, for the package that is not yet installed by delphi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*.apk files are basically zip files, so you can have a look at the single resources at least to get the app icon. The ApplicationManifest.xml is howewer compiled into some binary format, so this might be a bit harder to decode (but there are answers that show code for that task as well here: [How to parse the AndroidManifest.xml file inside an .apk package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package)).