# How to grab version name, version code, package name and minsdk level of an apk by using php

Tags: php, parsing, apk

I need a class or maybe a function to get version name, version code, package name and minsdk level from an apk file.

I found apk parser php class but in server it do not work fine.

I found this function but this function has error too.

```
function apps_infosfromapk($file)
{
global $AAPT_DIR;

$infos=array();
$retour = array();
exec ($AAPT_DIR." l -a ".realpath($file),$retour);

$txt = "";
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof ($retour); $i++)
    $txt .= $retour[$i];

$t1 = explode('android:versionName(0x0101021c)="',$txt);
$t3 = explode('"',$t1[1]);

$version = $t3[0];

$t2 = explode ('package="', $txt);
$t4 = explode ('"', $t2[1]);

$package = $t4[0];

$t5 = explode('A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x',$txt);
$t6 = explode(' ',$t5[1]);

$minSdk = intval($t6[0]);


$txt2=explode('android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.',$txt);

$it=0;
$permissions="";
for($i=1;$i<sizeof($txt2);$i++)
{
    $tmp=explode('"',$txt2[$i]);
    if($it==0)
        $permissions.=$tmp[0];
    else
        $permissions.=";".$tmp[0];

    $it++;
}



$infos[0]=$version; 
$infos[1]=$package;
$infos[2]=$minSdk;
$infos[3]=$permissions;

return $infos;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a difficult job to parse the file, it's not even in binary format. The reason why your scripts won't work might be due to linux/windows differences, I wonder why the author does not use PHP built-in file/directory functions which are os independend.. I don't think someone will write the function for you so you might provide the errors you get with the code you already have.
[APK Fileformat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29)

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to find that in PHP, but without good solution. Here are some related threads:

1. [Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014369/php-how-to-get-version-from-android-apk-file)
2. [Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552667/get-application-information-from-an-apk-using-php-script/7552765#7552765)

The most popular solution is to use `aapt dump badging myapp.apk` instead, you can get all the information in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Here is another code in java hope that will help you:

[Java](https://code.google.com/p/android4me/source/browse/src/android4me/res/AXMLParser.java)

And I have found a PHP script it meets all your needs, but still need the help of **aapt**.

```
function readApkInfoFromFile($apk_file, $get_icon = false){
   exec("/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.0/aapt d badging {$apk_file}", $out, $return);
   $temp_path = FCPATH . 'cache/temp/'.md5($apk_file).'/';

   if($return == 0){
        @mkdir($temp_path);
        $str_out = implode("\n", $out);
        $out = null;

        #icon
        if($get_icon){
            $pattern_icon = "/icon='(.+)'/isU";
            preg_match($pattern_icon, $str_out, $m);
            $info['icon'] = $m[1];
            if($info['icon']){
                //$command = "unzip {$apk_file} {$info['icon']} -d " . $temp_path;
                 $command = '7z x "' . $apk_file . '" -y -aos -o"' . $temp_path . '" ' . $info['icon'];
                 //exit($command);
                //mkdirs("/tmp/".$info['icon'],true);
                exec($command);
                $info['icon'] = $temp_path . $info['icon'];
            }
        }


        $pattern_name = "/application: label='(.*)'/isU";
        preg_match($pattern_name, $str_out,$m);
        $info['lable']=$m[1];


        $pattern_sys_name = "/package: name='(.*)'/isU";
        preg_match($pattern_sys_name, $str_out,$m);
        $info['sys_name']=$m[1];


        $pattern_version_code = "/versionCode='(.*)'/isU";
        preg_match($pattern_version_code, $str_out,$m);
        $info['version_code']=$m[1];


        $pattern_version = "/versionName='(.*)'/isU";
        preg_match($pattern_version, $str_out,$m);
        $info['version']=$m[1];


        $pattern_sdk = "/sdkVersion:'(.*)'/isU";
        if(preg_match($pattern_sdk, $str_out,$m)){
            $info['sdk_version']=$m[1];
            if($info['sdk_version']){
                $sdk_names = array(3=>"1.5",4=>"1.6",7=>"2.1",8=>"2.2",10=>'2.3.3',11=>"3.0",12=>"3.1",13=>"3.2",14=>"4.0");
                if($sdk_names[$info['sdk_version']]){
                    $info['os_req'] = "Android {$sdk_names[$info['sdk_version']]}";
                }
            }
        }


        $pattern_perm = "/uses-permission:'(.*)'/isU";
        preg_match_all($pattern_perm, $str_out,$m);
        if(isset($m[1])){
            foreach($m[1] as $mm){
                $info['permissions'][] = $mm;
            }
        }


        $pattern_features = "/uses-feature:'(.*)'/isU";
        preg_match_all($pattern_features, $str_out,$m);
        if(isset($m[1])){
            foreach($m[1] as $mm){
                $info['features'][] = $mm;
            }
        }

        $info['apk_info'] = $str_out;
        return $info;
    }
    return false;
}
```