# Is there a way to be notified when APK fails to being installed?

Tags: android, installation, apk

Im writing an application. 
In the application i download programatically an APK and start an
intent which launches the APK installtion.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")),
                "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
```

it all works well.

but when i try, for example, to launch an installation of a coruupted APK
There's a dialog which comes up:
[image]

I want to be notified when there's a problem installing the APK (corrupted APK, not enough space, etc...).

So , is there a way (Event or something) to be notified about that, so I can replace
the "Parse error" defalt dialog with my own dialog?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this method will work in all the potential situations but I have been testing and at least works for me.

I have not found information about detecting installation errors in Android so I try to preemptively detect if the apk file is corrupted.

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package), apks are simply jarfiles with dalvik codes. So you can use a zip decompression to detect the file have been corrupted and any problem parsing the package.

```
boolean corruptedApkFile = false;
try {
     new JarFile(updateFileFullPath); //Detect if the file have been corrupted
} catch (Exception ex) {
     corruptedApkFile = true;
}
```