# read res folder from an apk

Tags: android, apk

I want to read all the xml files in res folder.
I able to read Manifest file using jar `AXMLPrinter2.jar`
Same way i am trying to read xml files in res folder like below,

```
java -jar 'AXMLPrinter2.jar' 'account_list_item.xml' >'account_list_item.txt'
```

but it shows some exception like bellow,

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 109
    at android.content.res.StringBlock.getShort(StringBlock.java:231)
    at android.content.res.StringBlock.getString(StringBlock.java:91)
    at android.content.res.AXmlResourceParser.getName(AXmlResourceParser.java:140)
    at test.AXMLPrinter.main(AXMLPrinter.java:56)
```

Is there any way?

Answer (score 5):

I think AXMLPrinter2.jar needs that you first extract the XML files from the APK. You can do that with [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/), which already transforms the files into a human-readable form.

Use like this:

```
apktool decode --no-src yourapk.apk
```

Comment: --no-src means you do not want to do anything with the code, you only want to extract resources.

Comment: the files you get are already in text form, you do not need AXMLPrinter2.jar anymore

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://code.google.com/p/android4me/issues/detail?id=11) and [this](http://hi.baidu.com/ghcghc/item/ecbaa1ce997cb225a0b50ac2)
if apk's minSdkVersion >= 7, it didn't work

**UPDATE:**
[found this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10452398/1181782)