# unable to decode XML files from APK?

Tags: android, xml, apktool

I am trying to decode a APK file, here I have successfully decoded java/Class files

But I need AndroidManifest and Layout.XML files

when I tried with ApkTool its working for all other APK. Except My APK which I need to Decode...

I am getting all SMALI files..But I need XML files,

I used [APKTool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1755243), [SuperAPKtool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2623725) etc,..But no result except SMALL files..

What could be the problem.. How to View XML files

How ever I can see XML file name when I open APK with WINRAR.. But I want to view the XML content..

Please Suggest me of this kind...

Comment: Thank you @ Anand Singh Sir Your Tutorial worked thanks a lot... I UpVoted some of your Best Answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use AxmlPrinter to decode xml files from apk,You can download the jar from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android4me/downloads/detail?name=AXMLPrinter2.jar&),To decode your xml in your terminal run the following command

```
java -jar ./AXMLPrinter2.jar Filename.xml >Filename.txt
```

An example of decoding your manifest will look like

```
java -jar ./AXMLPrinter2.jar AndroidManifest.xml >AndroidManifest.txt
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sir Here I am getting Out of Bounds excepetion for layout/XML files manifest.xml is working  what to do...

Comment: refer to the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586897/read-res-folder-from-an-apk

Comment: Sir Here I am Unable to extrat XML from APk toool ,.... I am getting .smali files only... Any suggetion

Comment: It works for the Manifest file. It fails to work on the other .xml files

Comment: How do I do this if I am boycotting java?