# How to parse android application basic information from its market link?

Tags: android, android-manifest

It is possible to parse some information from the apk file using a tool as mentioned here:

[How to parse the AndroidManifest.xml file inside an .apk package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package)

My requirement is to parse information like Application name,description, image urls from a link like :

[market://details?id=com.replica.replicaisland](http://market://details?id=com.replica.replicaisland)

- Is there any standard way to parse this information without having the apk file ?
- is there any RSS feed available based on the identifier "com.replica.replicaisland" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open source library [android-market-api](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) created by some developers which allow you retrieve some basic app info directly from google's official android market, worth to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

For the first thing you could just download the webpage from the web browser version of the link which would be https://market.android.com/details?id=com.replica.replicaisland
From there you could parse through the source of the page in your own creative way.

As with RSS feed, no clue.

Comment: That is a possibility, but a difficult and non generic way,my parser would always have to keep track of current structure of market webpages.

Comment: I am afraid, that **any** look onto market pages, through any instrument, "would always have to keep track of current structure of market webpages", however sad it is. And you will have to wait for a new vwersion of instrument, too. +1 to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) and [ApplicationInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html) to see if it has everything you need.

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
    Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 

    try {
        ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageInfo.packageName, 0);
        String appFile = appInfo.sourceDir;

        long installed = new File(appFile).lastModified();              
        Log.d(TAG, "lastModified = " + installed);

        //Drawable icon = appInfo.loadIcon(pm);
        //Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)icon).getBitmap();               
    }           
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```