# Get Apk content in php

Tags: php, android

I want to know, is there any way to get content of Apk file like permission, min-sdk version and the current version in PHP ?!

Comment: does it work for you? minsdk and vercode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APKs are just ZIP files.  If you unzip them and read AndroidManifest.xml, you should be able to get everything you need to know.

See also:  [How to parse the AndroidManifest.xml file inside an .apk package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2097813/362536)