# Compare downloaded apk file version with installed one version programmaticaly

Tags: android, version, apk

I wanted to know that is it possible to find version of an apk file that i've downloaded from the server?
i can retrieve the version of my app that is installed on device but i want to check installed app version on device with the downloaded apk file version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot easily get the version of the APK file you downloaded until you have installed it.

That being said, you can unzip the APK file (its just a zip file) and parse the AndroidManifest.xml to get the value of the version code. 
 Since the AndroidManifest.xml you extract is a binary file, you will need to write some code to parse it. It's not as simple as inspecting a plain text file.

Check out this post on how to parse the AndroidManifest which has been extracted from an APK.

[How to parse the AndroidManifest.xml file inside an .apk package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package)

Answer (score 1):

```
PackageManager manager = this.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", 0);
String packageName = info.packageName;
int versionCode = info.versionCode;
String versionName = info.versionName;
```

Replace `com.whatsapp` with your package name.

Comment: thank you for rapid response ,i think this gives me the version of app that is already installed on device , i want to get version of downloaded apk file and compare it with installed one.

Comment: I do not think it's possible to get the version code even before you install it :/ I'll have a lookaround and see if there's anything!