# Is there an emacs mode that handles Android XML?

Tags: android, xml, emacs, apk

If I open a .apk file with Emacs, it shows me the archive just fine, but if I select the AndroidManifest.xml file, all I get is gobbledegook, because the XML is Android's binary XML encoding.

My google-fu has failed me in locating an emacs mode that understands Android Binary XML. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you can't find anything, the encoding is basically just 16bit characters-  ignore every other character in a string as garbage and its readable.

Comment: the mode nxml is for xml in general

Comment: According to the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2097813/113848), the encoding is more complex than UTF-16.

Comment: nxml cannot handle it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe any emacs XML mode would decode the binary XML format directly. However, there is a small perl script that can turn the binary XML into readable XML here: http://code.google.com/p/android-random/source/browse/trunk/axml2xml/axml2xml.pl

When loading a binary XML in emacs, I select the whole buffer, and run 'shell-command-on-region', specifying axml2xml.pl as the command. It's kludgy, but it works, for reading at least but not writing.