# How to PROPERLY check android permission dynamically

Tags: android, permissions, package, android-manifest, android-context

Multiple choice question:

which of the follow will correctly check whether or not an application has a certain permission declared in their AndroidManifest.xml?

```
getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

or

```
getContext().getPackageManager().checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, getContext().getPackageName()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

Basically, i got scared from the android documentation of what `checkCallingOrSelfPermission` claims -> it grants an IPC permissions if you just check for it?? what does that even mean?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkCallingOrSelfPermission(java.lang.String)

So any explanation on the true differences would be awesome :D

*note: I am giving this code in a library, so i am only allowed to check permissions at runtime, unless you know of a better way.

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding (which might be wrong, as I did not work much with IPC, yet):

Given that your code is executed from another application (e.g. your library was not compiled into the application, but exposed to a third party using `Binder` or something like that), you can use [`checkCallingPermission`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkCallingPermission%28java.lang.String%29) to check if the third party application has the given permission, while [`checkCallingOrSelfPermission`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkCallingOrSelfPermission%28java.lang.String%29) includes permissions from the application your library was compiled into.

You need to handle caller's permissions separately as you could leak permissions to other applications when checking the own permissions, too. From the [security tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html):

> Do not leak permission-protected data. This occurs when your app
>   exposes data over IPC that is only available because it has a specific
>   permission, but does not require that permission of any clients of
>   it’s IPC interface.
>
> [...]
>
> If providing an interface that does require access controls, use
>   `checkCallingPermission()` to verify whether the caller has a required
>   permission. This is especially important before accessing a service on
>   behalf of the caller, as the identify of your application is passed to
>   other interfaces.

The package manager way you describe checks *only* the permissions of the application your library was compiled into.

So, if your code is not executed from another process you probably don't have to care about the difference. Else, use the package manager way or [clear the calling identity stuff](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html#clearCallingIdentity%28%29) if you're interested in whether *you* can perform an task; additionally check the caller's permissions if you wish to check if *the calling process* could perform the task, too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method:

```
//for example, permission can be "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
public boolean hasPermission(String permission) 
{
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        if (info.requestedPermissions != null) {
            for (String p : info.requestedPermissions) {
                if (p.equals(permission)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This was originally my answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236801/programmatically-retrieve-permissions-from-manifest-xml-in-android/18237962#18237962).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Context.checkCallingorSelfPermission()` function for this. Here is an example

```
private boolean checkWriteExternalPermission()
{

    String permission = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
    int res = getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
    return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);            
}
```