# How to get AndroidManifest.xml of an android app

Tags: android, android-manifest

Ho to get *AndroidManifest.xml* of an android app. It may be available in Google play store or may be installed in my tablet. I want to read the *intent-filter* tag.

Answer (score 2):

If its on device you can write your own tool to read the AndroidManifest.xml file of other packages. See: [How to parse the AndroidManifest.xml file inside an .apk package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package)

Otherwise I don't see how you can find out as there is no web API from the Google Play store to get this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the apk file with you, change the extension from .apk to.zip. Then unzip the file and you will get the AndroidManifest file in the unzipped folder.

There are some other tools to unpack apk files.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
း ࢘ )     À      4 R v    ´ Â Ú ø Ğ İ ƈ ƌ ƞ Ʋ Ȁ Ȋ Ȟ Ⱥ ɬ ʎ ˄ ˾ ͐ ͪ ; Ϧ Є Д ь Ѡ Ҥ Ԅ ր ׶ ٬ ۢ ݒ versionCode versionName 
minSdkVersion targetSdkVersion name icon label 
launchMode theme 
debuggable 
configChanges screenOrientation android *http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android   package manifest %com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets 2.6 uses-sdk uses-feature android.hardware.camera uses-permission android.permission.CAMERA android.permission.INTERNET 'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE application activity 2com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.ImageTargets 
intent-filter action android.intent.action.MAIN category  android.intent.category.LAUNCHER .com.hansem.ar.schedule.ReplaceScheduleActivity <com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.Launcher3DViewActivity 9com.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.VideoPlayerActivity 9com.hansem.ar.checkingengineoil.EngineOilCheckingActivity 9com.hansem.ar.checkingengineoil.EngineOilLauncherActivity 6com.hansem.ar.schedule.ReplaceScheduleLauncherActivity Acom.qualcomm.QCARSamples.ImageTargets.WiperBladesLauncherActivity ƀ8 țāȜāȌāɰāāāāā āāāāĀ   
 Ă`      
   ကÈ 
   ̀   ̀ ĂL      
  က

  က ă   Ă8 <     
   ̀ ă <  Ă8 ?     
   ̀ ă ?  Ă8 B     
   ̀ ă B  Ă8 L     
   ̀ ă L  Ă \     
  Ā^缋
  Ā
缊
  Āæ缂
     ሀ
  က Ă`      
   ̀ 
  က  

 ᄀಠ Ă$       Ă8      
   ̀ ă   Ă8       
  ! ̀! ă    ă   ă   Ă`      
  " ̀" 
  က  

 ᄀ  ă   Ă`      
  # ̀# 
  က  

 ᄀ  ă   Ă`      
  $ ̀$ 
  က  

 ᄀ  ă    Ă` ¡     
  % ̀% 
  က  

 ᄀ  ă ¥  Ă` ¦     
  Ā$缊
  & ̀& 
  က  ă ª  ĂL ¬     
  ' ̀' 
  က  ă ¯  ĂL ±     
  ( ̀( 
  က  ă ´  ă ¶  ă ¸  ā ¸
```

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur It wont be properly readable as its obfuscated. Still, things can be figured out like in his case - intent-filters. I have pasted the obfuscated manifest file in my answer. Intent filters can be seen

Comment: I don't have the apk file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the app "apps_Packages Info" which is [available from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.oF2pks.applicationsinfo/). It allows you to view any other installed app's activities, intents, permissions etc. and also to access the app's entire `AndroidManifest.xml`.