# Published unity android app has lower android version requirements than manifest

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, adt

I built a game in Unity and I'm trying to export to to Android.  I've set the min API in Android player settings to 14.  I've confirmed with the AndroidManifest.xml file in both temp/staging and assets/plugins/android that it reflects this.  It shows:

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I then exported directly into an APK file right from unity (not through eclipse).  I uploaded the APK to the google play store in beta mode.  However, when I look at the app screen on the play store I see: `Requires Android: 1.6 and up`.  Why is it doing this?

I'm thinking there might be a problem with the Manifest file but I'm not sure.  For example, I'm using AdMob so I have these permissions in the file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

But when I install the app through the beta link it tells me that no extra permissions are necessary.  AdMob is working though, I can see the banner ads and the impressions are showing up on my AdMob account.  I'm not sure if the no permissions needed thing is related to a bad manifest file or a beta store account.  **EDIT:** Actually if I install the APK manually then it does show the permissions, so I'm guessing it's just a beta thing and my permissions are fine.

To test, I've tried exporting the file as an Android Project, then importing into Eclipse.  When I try to do that, it successfully recognizes the project but even though the Finish button isn't greyed out it doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 0):

Decompile your APK file to read AndroidManifest.xml.

Look at this: [How to parse the AndroidManifest.xml file inside an .apk package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known bug, and it doesn't seem to affect published apps, so don't worry about it:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67234/why-does-my-game-display-the-wrong-required-android-version-on-google-play