# how to get application label from apk?

Tags: java, android, aapt

I have two questions.

First,
I already tried to find application label from APK file using aapt v0.2(fig1)
[image]

But, I cannot find application label from aapt v0.2-3303571

"Application-label:" is removed in  v0.2-3303571 and label is empty in application like fig2.
[image]

How can I get application label from apk?
Must I use only aapt v0.2? I want to use updated aapt.exe

Second,

I called aapt command using processbuilder in JAVA.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder( command.split("@-") );
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();      
InputStreamReader istream = new  InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(istream);
String res = br.readLine();
```

I received normal result using aapt v0.2
But I received abnoraml string like "'aapt' is ◆◆◆◆◆◆ ?? ◆◆" using aapt v0.2-3303571.

What should I do for solving this problem?

Comment: If I get it right your main question is how to read AndroidManifest.xml in it's binary xml format, correct?

Comment: My main question is how to read Application Label In APK File.

Comment: How to read Application Label Infomation in Android.xml in apk

Comment: Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22006681/150978). May be you have to read the string resources as well as the label is often localized.