# AirWatch seems to be incompatible with Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0-beta1

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, airwatch

After changing my top level build.gradle to use the `Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0-beta3` along with `Gradle 4.1`, `AirWatch` can't read the info (like versionCode and versionName) from the APK.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    roomVersion = '1.0.0-alpha9'
    supportLibVersion = '26.0.1'
}
```

Is this a known issue? Any workaround?

Comment: This seems to be a known issue in the AW realm.  It seems they have it on the roadmap but no defined date to put it in. Some are hoping 9.2.3

Answer (score 8):

Airwatch has an issue with the new AAPT2 tool which seems to compile the Manifest.xml file in a compressed form in contrast to AAPT. AAPT2 became the standard with Android Studio 3 but you can get back easily to AAPT by putting the line

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

in the gradle.properties file of your project. Solved at least in our project the problem.

Comment: This worked for me, airwatch can now parse the meta data from the manifest after adding this.  Nice catch!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I just wanted to ask, if you have found out anything new about this topic, since our clients use AirWatch and we have run into a similar problem after updating gradle.

Specifically after updating from Android Studio 2 to Android Studio 3 and thus changing all gradle stuff coming with it.

Comment: I didn't find anything, but changing my project to use the previous version of Gradle even with Android Studio 3 made AirWatch recognize our APK.

Comment: Interesting. I took a different approach and just used Android Studio 2 to compile it. Had to change some gradle stuff, but I think that should fix it. When I have the result from the client I'll post another comment.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, Airwatch has a limitation where it will not update the app compiled with Android gradle plugin 3.0.

There are 2 work arounds.
1. Build the apk using the gradle plugin 2.3.3
or 
2. Upload the apk built using gradle plugin 3.0 as a separate app on the console. Define App/ID version code manually and deploy.